# Not able to create configurable product with more than 30+ variations

Tags: configurable-product, magento-1

While creating configurable products with more than 30+ variation and click on save. The variable products were created and the configurable product was missing, I cant able to create new configurable product. Does anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create via CSV.
Just follow the format to create configurable product